# Play Store - Ready to Publish State

Tags: android, google-play

Hi i have uploaded my app to play store but till now it's in Ready to Publish state. Why is it i am unable to understand this? I uploaded my app on sep 13, 2013.In the attached pic on left side you can ***apk, store listing and Pricing & Distribution*** are ticked **Green**. If i hadn't  fulfilled any part then it won't be **Green**
[image]

As you can see it on screenshot. Any idea why is it?

Comment: Yeah i too thought that i have added all the filed marked with * and also had uploaded images for all filed mobile, 7 - inch tanlet and 10 inch tablet. You can see on the pic on left side all required filed are ticked green

Comment: You still haven't completed something. When it says "Ready to publish" it doesn't mean someone at Google has to take action - it's your responsibility to publish / un-publish apps.

Comment: @Squonk ok i'll look onto it. if i have missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not the owner and have been added to a publish account this inability to publish can be also down to the permissions you have been granted. I had this with a client and they had not granted me access to manage production or manage alpha/beta apks. Once they granted this to me I had to log out and back in for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 14):

Try it in firefox. The drop down didn't open for me in google chrome.

Comment: Also worked for me.  Seems amazing that Google's website doesn't work with Google's browser...

Comment: It's June 2015 and the button still does not work in Chrome !!! I don't get this :)

Answer (score 3):

If Publish button does not appear in IE, try Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Publish the app manually by clicking Publish option from "Ready to Publish" dropdown.

Comment: yepp i did that too but not any action. Is it like we need admin access to publish as i am not admin in account it's client's account.

Comment: Do you have access to this account? Btw is the option to Publish the app getting displayed there?

Comment: As seen in above picture Ready to Publish is displayed and when i click them nothing happens not any action. I have access to the account but i am not admin.

Comment: Yess, Publish this app is displayed. But when i click nothing happens

Comment: The dropdown doesn't work in some browsers. Try firefox.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the "Ready to Publish" button wasn't doing anything. I assume this is the problem you're having.

I opened an incognito window and signed in as a different user (owner rather than admin) and it worked fine. So, one of those two things solved it, but I'm not sure which. Go ahead and try either or both.

FWIW, this was in Chromium 35.0.1916.114.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the people who have answered for the question. It helped me lot. You need to publish the app manually by yourself. I am just trying to combine all those answers in one:

1. You must have admin privilege to publish the app so make sure you have one to publish app.
2. Try it in different browser. (In fact I didn't had to change the browser.)

Kudos to people who answered it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store listing , click on review then rollout

Answer (score 0):

In the new Play Console, go to Publishing overview. Click the blue **Review and publish** button. [image]